# ImageButton effect on Android 3.0+

Tags: android, button, effect

I want to have an onTouch effect like the Home Button on Android 3.0+.

Is there a property to do so easily?
Or I have to do it all myself? And how?

Thanks!

UPDATE:
Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrCrd.jpg
I would like to have the same blue, circle, fade-out effect.

Comment: elaborate a bit more on what you mean by "like the home button" can you explain it or even better provide picture / video link?

Comment: I have added a screenshot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about is called the **Navigation Bar**. The animation and circle effect used when you touch a button are from a custom class that's extending `ImageView`.

[You can view the full source for that class here.](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/ics/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/policy/KeyButtonView.java)

As far as the Holo blue color goes, you can visit the [Android Design Guidelines - Color section](http://developer.android.com/design/style/color.html) to look at all of the colors used in **Ice Cream Sandwich**. Move your mouse over a specific color in the palette to learn the corresponding hex value.

I'll leave this example here in case you decide not to use the `KeyButtonView` class.

**Holo selector example**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

<item android:drawable="@color/holo_blue_dark" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/holo_blue_dark" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. I use on the background of an ImageButton. The fade-out is the same. But could I apply the circle? And how to get the correct holo_blue_dark color that are from system?